# Typescript - Create a MultiProxy<T> object that implements an interface and is a proxy to an array of objects that implement the same interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here's what I want to do in Typescript:

- `T` is an `interface`
- `MultiProxy<T>` will hold a list of children that also implement T.
- `MultiProxy<T>` also implements `T`
- Each method call of `MultiProxy<T>` will call the same method on all its children of type `T`.

How can this be achieved with Typescript?

Note: `Proxy<T>` doesn't support this scenario.

Comment: Could you flesh this out into a [mre] with some specific use cases?  Right now it's not clear how what you're asking is possible.  Let's say we have `interface Foo {x: string, y: number}`.  Then `MultiProxy<Foo>` would... what? There are no methods on `Foo`. Do you intend the interfaces to *only* have methods?  So `interface Bar { x(): string, y(a: number): number }`.  So then a `MultiProxy<Bar>` would... what? What does its `x()` method return? Maybe you want the interfaces to only have `void`-returning methods?  This is the kind of thing that a good set of example use cases would establish.

Comment: Like, maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2EzxW) works for you, but it's all based on wild guesses about what `MultiProxy<T>` is actually supposed to do.  Some concrete use cases would help.